# Can Google protobuf parse video streams?

Tags: java, android, c++, protocol-buffers

Excuse me, can Google protobuf be used to parse video streams?
The client is Android, and the server is C++, using netty+protobuf communications, server connection monitors, and now want to get video streams from the server.I'm not sure it will work。

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but why would you think GPB might be able to parse video streams? It's a serialization mechanism - I assume you could wrap the raw bytes in a GPB message but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have little experience and I am not sure. Now use netty+GBP communications server, if you want to transport video stream, how should I do?